# Taking two mathrandom values and adding them on loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to make a game of dice where I add the values of both the dice and give the sum. You get another turn if both the dice end up on the same number (such as 2 and 2 which is 4) then you roll the dice again and the 2 new numbers get added to the previous sum (like 4 mentioned earlier). 
For example - 
1st try 3 and 3, sum is 6.
2nd try 4 and 5, sum is 6 + 4 + 5 = 15

I'm able to get the first sum right, but the subsequent numbers are getting messed up sometimes even giving twice as much.

```
function oneRandom(){
    var my1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 ) +1 ;   
    var my2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 ) +1 ;
     var num1 = Number(my1);
    var num2 = Number(my2);

    var sum = num1 + num2;
    console.log(sum);
    var resultfield = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h1>"+sum+"</h1>";

    document.getElementById("cilc").style.display = "none";
    if (getImage.src == get2.src){
        document.getElementById("cilc").style.display = "block";
        var sum2 = num1 + num2;
        var total = sum2 + sum;
    var resultfield = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<h1>"+total+"</h1>";
    }

}
```

The getImage and get2 are arrays to match dice images to give another turn in case of same numbers loading.

Comment: You are using the same values for the second roll (var sum2 = num1 + num2); you should re roll them again if   dice is rolled with same numbers first. Also there is no code for changing image sources and e.t.c It seems  not whole  version of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```js
function rollDice (times) {
    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(6));
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(6));
    console.log(times, num1, num2);
    var total = num1 + num2;
    return num1 === num2 ? total + rollDice(times + 1) : total;
}

console.log(`result is ${rollDice(0)}`);
```

Comment: Second roll might trigger next roll  again. Certainly you could do something like that  return num1 === num2  && times == 0? total + rollDice(times + 1) : total; But it is a bit awkward

Comment: @Oleg In second trigger also if it matches we need to have one more trigger right?

Comment: based on game rules it might only one extra roll of dices. But I just realized that this game might be based on post owner  rules and his rules might allow a lot of extra rolls .